# Functional equation, inverse w.r.t composition, which function gives identity?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Given a function $$f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},\qquad z\mapsto \frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\text{,}$$ I want to know a function $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, for which holds $$\left(f\circ g\right)\left(z\right) = f\left(g\left(z\right)\right) = z\text{.}$$

So to speak, I want to know the inverse w.r.t. composition, which gives the idendity map $\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb{C}}=z$.

I do not not how to proceed, any help is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $w=g(z)$. Then
$$ f(g(z))=z \implies f(w)=z, $$
or
$$ z = \frac{1-2w-\sqrt{1-4w}}{2w}. $$
Now rearrange this equation to solve for $w$.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it this way, but I always chose the positive branch of the square root and consequently got $1/z$ instead of $z$. Now, starting the calculation afresh I payed more attention and finally got the right result.